# ReactJS: one digit input can end up with multiple '0's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Basically, I want a little box with only one digit, it "works" fine until you try to put multiple '0', then in the box, multiple 0000 persist.

[image: multiple 0]
[image: console logs]

The code

```
const InputBox = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = el => {
    const newValue = el.target.value;
    console.log(newValue);
    const lastNumber = parseInt(
      newValue.toString().slice(-1),
    );
    console.log(lastNumber);
    setValue(lastNumber);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type='number'
      pattern='[0-9]'
      min='0'
      max='9'
      id='numberInput'
      maxLength={1}
      minLength={1}
      value={value}
      onInput={handleChange}
      // onChange={handleChange}
      className='inputBox'
    />
  );
};

export default InputBox;
```

How to make it so I have only one digit at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't need to parse to int or to string, just slice and set value.
- minLength and maxLength doesn't work in `<input type="number">`.

```
const InputBox = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (el) => {
    let newValue = el.target.value;
    if (newValue.length > 1) {
      newValue = newValue.slice(0, 1);
    }
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      pattern="[0-9]"
      min="0"
      max="9"
      id="numberInput"
      value={value}
      onInput={handleChange}
      className="inputBox"
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: in my case I only care for the last thing typed, so: `newValue = newValue.slice(-1)` just take the last digit and then `newValue = newValue.toString().replace(/\D/g, '');` adding this because for some reason you can still type "e" and "." in a number type input. this did help getting rid of the "e" but not the "." (i've tried even with other regex)...

Answer (score 0):

This could work out

```js
const handleChange = el => {
    const newValue = el.target.value;
    const lastNumber = newValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')
    setValue(lastNumber);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text" maxlength="1" 
      value={value}
      onInput={handleChange}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the type coercion to string of your state (*you can always `Number(value)` when you need a number type for computations*) then you can simply slice off the last char of the value and if it ends up being a falsey (`''`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`) value fallback to `0` to allow coercion back to `"0"` when assigning to the `value` prop of the `input`. Also, the `minLength`|`maxLength`|`pattern` attributes only work when doing field validation in a form.

```
const handleChange = (el) => {
  const { value } = el.target;
  setValue(value.slice(-1) || 0);
};
```

[image: Edit zen-tree-p9yt1]

```
const InputBox = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (el) => {
    const { value } = el.target;
    setValue(value.slice(-1) || 0);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      min="0"
      max="9"
      id="numberInput"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      className="inputBox"
    />
  );
};
```